# $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n)!}=\cosh(1)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, factorial

Is there any way to show that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n)!}=\cosh(1) = \frac{1+e^2}{2e}$$ knowing that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}=e$$
I guess that we can also show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)!}=\sinh(1) $ but I have no clue of how to get rid of the "2" in the factorial...

Comment: $\frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2}=\sinh x = x + x^3/3! + x^5/5! + \cdots$

Comment: I was thinking of maybe a more direct way without using a formula for sinh(x) and cosh(x)

Comment: Just use the power series expansion of $e^x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{ x^k }{ k!}$

Answer (score 2):

No, the fact that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac 1{n!} = e$ is insufficient (by any reasonable interpretation of what it means to "use a fact"). However, you could reach your result if you use the additional fact that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} = e^{-1}.
$$
In particular, we can note that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n)!} = \frac 12 \left( 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} + 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}
\right)
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} = e$, and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} = x$.
I claim that $x = 1/e$.  Since the series converge absolutely, we can rearrange

$$ \eqalign{e x &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} \frac{(-1)^m}{m!}\cr
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^k \frac{1}{n!} \frac{(-1)^{k-n}}{(k-n)!}\cr
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{n=0}^k  {k \choose n} (-1)^{k-n}\cr
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} (1-1)^k}$$
where the last equality uses the binomial theorem.  But $(1-1)^k = 0^k = 1$ for $k=0$
(check the sum explicitly for the case $k=0$ if you're uncomfortable with this)
and $0$ for $k > 0$, so we conclude that $ex = 1$.

And now, as others have mentioned,
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n)!} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1 + (-1)^n}{n!} = \frac{e + 1/e}{2} = \cosh(1)$$

Answer (score 0):

Write down the series expansions for $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$ around $0$. Add the two series and divide by $2$. Similarly, you can subtract them, to get $\sinh$.
$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\\e^{-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n!}$$
When you add these two expressions, the odd terms will cancel. If you subtract them, the even terms will cancel out.